# Performance problems during Neo4J import / conversion with multiple steps

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

We import via apoc.load.jdbc(...) around 100'000 nodes to Neo4J 3.4.0. The import script consists of several steps. Among other things, the original graph is converted into an extended graph, which consists of about 500'000 nodes at the end.

The complete import takes about 3 minutes. But, **we had to implement sleeps of 20 seconds between the steps**. Otherwise the import takes a multiple of 3 minutes. Without the slepps the import would be unter 1 minute finished. Anyway, sleeps are not the way to get a programm up and running...

- Indexes are created, with "CREATE INDEX ON :NodeXY(fieldXyId)"
- Indexes are ONLINE, tested with "CALL db.awaitIndex(':NodeXY(fieldXyId)')"

What could be the reason for the needing of the sleeps? Is there a way to check that Neo is ready for next queries/conversions?

Any feedback is welcome - THANKS!

Comment: is it an initial load ?

Comment: if it is, I have seen such a behaviour due to the query planner. In fact the stats of the DB is empty, so the planner will not produce the good query plan. To avoid this kind of behaviour you need to enforce in cypher the use of indexes.

Comment: yes, it is an initial load. Thanks for the hint, we will check it!

Comment: @logisima: I haven't foud a way which works. One simple step looks like "MATCH (x:X) 
MATCH (y:Y {id:x.id}) 
    USING INDEX y:Y(id) 
CREATE (z:Z {id:x.id}) 
  SET 
    z.foo=0,
 z.bar=x.bar" and didn't end in time. I also haven't found a way to set a index hint for MERGE or CREATE operations, which may be the cause...